# How do I evaluate this $ \lim \frac{\zeta(n)} {({n)!}} , n\to\infty $ if it was existed?

Tags: limits, factorial, zeta-functions

Is there someone who can show me how do I evaluate this limit

$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}  \frac{\zeta(n)} {n!} $$ if it exists ?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What does $m!$ mean when $m$ is a negative integer? The Gamma function does not extend to negative integers, so it isn't that.

Comment: ok, thank just fixo now it's fixed

Comment: Well, $\zeta(n)$ is bounded for integers $n>1$...

Comment: sorry for my bad question

Comment: I am curious: did you meet the problem somewhere, did you miscopy something... what happened?

Comment: You sure no typo?

Comment: Close the question?

Answer (score 3):

It is trivially zero, because $\zeta$ is a positive decreasing function over the integers $n\geq 2$.

Answer (score 3):

First note that 
$$
0<\zeta(n)<\zeta(2)
$$
for $n>2$. Thus 
$$
0\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{\zeta(n)}{n!}\right|<\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\zeta(2)}{n!}.
$$
Can you finish from here?